# Migrating from mule 3.6.2 to 3.8.2

Tags: java, mule

I am working on upgrading an existing application from 3.6.2 to 3.8.2. The REST calls are working after the configuration changes. But getting NullPointerException in StaxDataBinding.java when running the flow for SOAP call. The Service is returning 200 but at the end the flow fails with status code 500.

Old config file for Mule 3.6.2:

```
<flow name="testws-srr">
       <http:inbound-endpoint host="${app.host}" port="${app.port}" path="testWs" exchange-pattern="request-response" doc:name="HTTP">
          <cxf:proxy-service/>
       </http:inbound-endpoint>
       <msr:resolve-endpoint serviceName="TestService" basicAuthSupport="true"/>
       <http:outbound-endpoint ref="msr-resolvedEndpoint" exchange-pattern="request-response" responseTimeout="30000" doc:name="HTTP">
          <cxf:proxy-client/>
       </http:outbound-endpoint>
       <custom-exception-strategy class="com.mule.errorhandling.exception.CustomExceptionHandlingStrategy" doc:name="Custom Exception Strategy">
         <spring:property name="code" value="TA102" />
         <spring:property name="message" value="${error.TA102}"/>
      </custom-exception-strategy>
    </flow>
```

flows-config.xml for 3.8.2:

```
<flow name="testws-srr">
      <http:listener config-ref="msr-listener-httpConnector" path="testWs" doc:name="HTTP"/>
      <cxf:proxy-service doc:name="CXF" />      
      <msr:resolve-endpoint serviceName="resultsService" basicAuthSupport="true" />      
      <cxf:proxy-client doc:name="CXF"/>      
      <sfhttp:request config-ref="msr-request-httpConnector" path="" method="POST" responseTimeout="15000" doc:name="HTTP">
         <http:success-status-code-validator values="200,500" />
      </http:request>
      <transformer ref="statusTransformer" />
      <custom-exception-strategy class="com.mule.errorhandling.exception.CustomExceptionHandlingStrategy" doc:name="Custom Exception Strategy">
         <spring:property name="code" value="TA102" />
         <spring:property name="message" value="${error.TA102}" />
      </custom-exception-strategy>
   </flow>
```

I am getting this error when adding cxf:proxy-service tag -

```
2017-09-25 10:39:42,844 logLevel="WARN" [[-auto-esb].msr-listener-httpConnector.worker.01] org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain: Interceptor for {http://support.cxf.module.mule.org/}ProxyService has thrown exception, unwinding now
java.lang.NullPointerException
   at org.apache.cxf.databinding.stax.StaxDataBinding$XMLStreamDataWriter.write(StaxDataBinding.java:147) ~[cxf-rt-core-2.7.18.jar:2.7.18]
   at org.apache.cxf.databinding.stax.StaxDataBinding$XMLStreamDataWriter.write(StaxDataBinding.java:135) ~[cxf-rt-core-2.7.18.jar:2.7.18]
   at org.apache.cxf.databinding.stax.StaxDataBinding$XMLStreamDataWriter.write(StaxDataBinding.java:131) ~[cxf-rt-core-2.7.18.jar:2.7.18]
   at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.AbstractOutDatabindingInterceptor.writeParts(AbstractOutDatabindingInterceptor.java:141) ~[cxf-api-2.7.18.jar:2.7.18]
   at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.BareOutInterceptor.handleMessage(BareOutInterceptor.java:68) ~[cxf-api-2.7.18.jar:2.7.18]
   at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:272) ~[cxf-api-2.7.18.jar:2.7.18]
   at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.resume(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:242) ~[cxf-api-2.7.18.jar:2.7.18]
   at org.mule.module.cxf.CxfInboundMessageProcessor$2.write(CxfInboundMessageProcessor.java:541) ~[mule-module-cxf-3.8.2.jar:3.8.2]
   at org.mule.tranformer.simple.ObjectToByteArray.doTranform(ObjectToByteArray.java:63) ~[mule-core-3.8.2.jar:3.8.2]
   at org.mule.tranformer.AbstractTranformer.tranform(AbstractTranformer.java:415) ~[mule-core-3.8.2.jar:3.8.2]
   at org.mule.DefaultMuleMessage.getPayload(DefaultMuleMessage.java:406) ~[mule-core-3.8.2.jar:3.8.2]
   at org.mule.DefaultMuleMessage.getPayload(DefaultMuleMessage.java:354) ~[mule-core-3.8.2.jar:3.8.2]
   at org.mule.DefaultMuleMessage.getPayloadAsBytes(DefaultMuleMessage.java:741) ~[mule-core-3.8.2.jar:3.8.2]
   at org.mule.module.http.internal.listener.HttpResponseBuilder.build(HttpResponseBuilder.java:208) ~[mule-module-http-3.8.2.jar:3.8.2]
   at org.mule.module.http.internal.listener.HttpMessageProcessorTemplate.doBuildResponse(HttpMessageProcessorTemplate.java:122) ~[mule-module-http-3.8.2.jar:3.8.2]
   at org.mule.module.http.internal.listener.HttpMessageProcessorTemplate.buildResponse(HttpMessageProcessorTemplate.java:112) ~[mule-module-http-3.8.2.jar:3.8.2]
   at org.mule.module.http.internal.listener.HttpMessageProcessorTemplate.sendResponseToClient(HttpMessageProcessorTemplate.java:86) ~[mule-module-http-3.8.2.jar:3.8.2]
   at org.mule.execution.AsyncResponseFlowProcessingPhase.runPhase(AsyncResponseFlowProcessingPhase.java:78) ~[mule-core-3.8.2.jar:3.8.2]
   at org.mule.execution.AsyncResponseFlowProcessingPhase.runPhase(AsyncResponseFlowProcessingPhase.java:35) ~[mule-core-3.8.2.jar:3.8.2]
   at org.mule.execution.PhaseExecutionEngine$InternalPhaseExecutionEngine.phaseSuccesfully(PhaseExecutionEngine.java:65) ~[mule-core-3.8.2.jar:3.8.2]
   at org.mule.execution.PhaseExecutionEngine$InternalPhaseExecutionEngine.phaseSuccesfully(PhaseExecutionEngine.java:69) ~[mule-core-3.8.2.jar:3.8.2]
   at com.mulesoft.mule.throttling.ThrottlingPhase.runPhase(ThrottlingPhase.java:187) ~[mule-module-throttling-ee-3.8.2.jar:3.8.2]
   at com.mulesoft.mule.throttling.ThrottlingPhase.runPhase(ThrottlingPhase.java:58) ~[mule-module-throttling-ee-3.8.2.jar:3.8.2]
   at org.mule.execution.PhaseExecutionEngine$InternalPhaseExecutionEngine.phaseSuccesfully(PhaseExecutionEngine.java:65) ~[mule-core-3.8.2.jar:3.8.2]
   at com.mulesoft.gateway.http.phases.GatewayValidationPhase.runPhase(GatewayValidationPhase.java:93) ~[gateway-core-3.8.2.jar:3.8.2]
   at com.mulesoft.gateway.http.phases.GatewayValidationPhase.runPhase(GatewayValidationPhase.java:49) ~[gateway-core-3.8.2.jar:3.8.2]
   at org.mule.execution.PhaseExecutionEngine$InternalPhaseExecutionEngine.phaseSuccesfully(PhaseExecutionEngine.java:65) ~[mule-core-3.8.2.jar:3.8.2]
   at org.mule.modules.cors.CorsPhase.runPhase(CorsPhase.java:113) ~[mule-module-cors-gw-3.8.2.jar:3.8.2]
   at org.mule.modules.cors.CorsPhase.runPhase(CorsPhase.java:40) ~[mule-module-cors-gw-3.8.2.jar:3.8.2]
   at org.mule.execution.PhaseExecutionEngine$InternalPhaseExecutionEngine.process(PhaseExecutionEngine.java:114) ~[mule-core-3.8.2.jar:3.8.2]
   at org.mule.execution.PhaseExecutionEngine.process(PhaseExecutionEngine.java:41) ~[mule-core-3.8.2.jar:3.8.2]
   at org.mule.execution.MuleMessageProcessingManager.processMessage(MuleMessageProcessingManager.java:32) ~[mule-core-3.8.2.jar:3.8.2]
   at org.mule.module.http.internal.listener.DefaultHttpListener$1.handleRequest(DefaultHttpListener.java:133) ~[mule-module-http-3.8.2.jar:3.8.2]
   at org.mule.module.http.internal.listener.grizzly.GrizzlyRequestDispatcherFilter.handleRead(GrizzlyRequestDispatcherFilter.java:83) ~[mule-module-http-3.8.2.jar:3.8.2]
   at org.glasfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119) ~[grizzly-framework-2.3.26.jar:2.3.26]
   at org.glasfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284) ~[grizzly-framework-2.3.26.jar:2.3.26]
   at org.glasfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201) ~[grizzly-framework-2.3.26.jar:2.3.26]
   at org.glasfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133) ~[grizzly-framework-2.3.26.jar:2.3.26]
   at org.glasfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112) ~[grizzly-framework-2.3.26.jar:2.3.26]
   at org.glasfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77) ~[grizzly-framework-2.3.26.jar:2.3.26]
   at org.glasfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:526) ~[grizzly-framework-2.3.26.jar:2.3.26]
   at org.glasfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112) ~[grizzly-framework-2.3.26.jar:2.3.26]
   at org.mule.module.http.internal.listener.grizzly.ExecutorPerServerAddressIOStrategy.run0(ExecutorPerServerAddressIOStrategy.java:102) ~[mule-module-http-3.8.2.jar:3.8.2]
   at org.mule.module.http.internal.listener.grizzly.ExecutorPerServerAddressIOStrategy.access$100(ExecutorPerServerAddressIOStrategy.java:30) ~[mule-module-http-3.8.2.jar:3.8.2]
   at org.mule.module.http.internal.listener.grizzly.ExecutorPerServerAddressIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(ExecutorPerServerAddressIOStrategy.java:125) ~[mule-module-http-3.8.2.jar:3.8.2]
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [?:1.8.0_111]
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [?:1.8.0_111]
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.8.0_111]
2017-09-25 10:39:42,848 logLevel="DEBUG" [[-auto-esb].msr-listener-httpConnector.worker.01] org.mule.module.http.internal.HttpMessageLogger: LISTENER
HTTP/1.1 500 
Content-Length: 0
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8
Date: Mon, 25 Sep 2017 15:39:42 GMT
Connection: close
```

Guessing if it has something to do with the response being multipart?

```
Content-Type: multipart/related; type="application/xop+xml"; boundary="uuid:7f7f18e7-44ab-44dc-bf18-33954bf602f9"; start="<root.message@cxf.apache.org>"; start-info="text/xml"
```

Answer (score 0):

This was resolved by adding parseResponse="false" in http request connector and similarly parseRequest="false" in http listener.

> Disabling HTTP Response Body Parsing: As with the HTTP Listener
>   Connector, when HTTP responses have a content type of
>   application/x-www-form-urlencoded or multipart/form-data, the HTTP
>   Request Connector automatically carries out a parsing of the message.
>   If you wish, you can disable this parsing functionality bydoing the
>   following:
>    •XML Editor: set the parseResponse attribute to false
>   •Studio UI: Untick the Parse Response checkbox in the Advanced tab of
>   the HTTP Request Connector

Reference: https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.8/http-request-connector